# Strip the Root node from XML

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery-sql

I have CustoInfo XML, which is which stored in the temporary table from another bigger table for some manipulation. I want to strip the root node and return all the elements lying below it without the namespaces added to any of the root's children.

```
 `DECLARE @tempCustomerInfo TABLE
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
CustInfo XML NULL
)

DECLARE @CustInfo XML
SET @CustInfo = '<Customer xmlns="Corp.Info.Customer"><Name><FName>Mark</FName>     <MName>A</MName><LName>Antony</LName></Name><Address><Street>Clare</Street><City>Clarkson</City></Address></Customer>'
 INSERT INTO @tempCustomerInfo SELECT @CustInfo

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'Corp.Info.Customer')   
SELECT CustInfo.query('/Customer/*') FROM @tempCustomerInfo`
```

It returns the output as below - with namespace added in every element.

```
   `<p1:Name xmlns:p1="Corp.Info.Customer">
  <p1:FName>Mark</p1:FName>
  <p1:MName>A</p1:MName>
 <p1:LName>Antony</p1:LName>
 </p1:Name>
 <p2:Address xmlns:p2="Corp.Info.Customer">
 <p2:Street>Clare</p2:Street>
<p2:City>Clarkson</p2:City>
</p2:Address>`
```

I require a cleaner xml like this

```
 `<Name >
  <FName>Mark</FName>
 <MName>A</MName>
 <LName>Antony</LName>
</Name>
<Address >
 <Street>Clare</Street>
<City>Clarkson</City>
```

`

Anyway to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note - if you find yourself needing to strip namespace information from XML, it's usually a sign of something going wrong somewhere - the namespace information is an essential part of the identity of the elements.

Comment: Here is what I am actually trying to achieve. I would have multiple records and have to put them all (name and address) under one single root (CustomerDetails). Once I have these details, I would use FOR XML AUTO , ELEMENTS to put them in a single document with a different namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast to `nvarchar(max)`, remove the namespace declaration and then cast back to `xml` again.

```sql
SELECT cast(replace(cast(CustInfo as nvarchar(max)), 'xmlns="Corp.Info.Customer"', '')
            as xml).query('Customer/*')
FROM @tempCustomerInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tempCustomerInfo TABLE
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
CustInfo XML NULL
)

DECLARE @CustInfo XML
SET @CustInfo = '<Customer xmlns="Corp.Info.Customer"><Name><FName>Mark</FName>     <MName>A</MName><LName>Antony</LName></Name><Address><Street>Clare</Street><City>Clarkson</City></Address></Customer>'
 INSERT INTO @tempCustomerInfo SELECT @CustInfo
;


WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'Corp.Info.Customer')  
SELECT t.c.query('declare default element namespace "Corp.Info.Customer";.')
FROM @CustInfo.nodes('/Customer/*') t(c)
```